# Organising folder structure and database queries with nodejs, express, mongoose using an MVC pattern

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am new to nodejs as well as mvc patterns. I am trying to create an app that utilises express, mongoose, ejs, passport. I am unsure as to where to place my database queries. At the moment I have started to add them into the controllers/routes.js file. Here is the approximate folder structure I have created so far:

```
|-- config

    -- database.js // Exports just the db url
    -- passport.js // Exports Passport local auth strategies (includes db connections)  

|-- controllers

    -- routes.js // Routes

|-- models

    -- user.js // Exports mongoose user schema

|-- public

|-- views

    -- home.ejs // Home ejs page
    -- signup.ejs // Sign up page
    -- user.ejs // User profile page

app.js // Express configure and server start etc...
```

I have followed a passport tutorial but the only db connections there exist in the config/passport.js file. At the moment I have placed a connection in the routes.js file but from what I have read these should go in the models folder. This is the code I have in my routes.js file:

```
//controllers/routes.js

//USER PROFILE ROUTE

app.get('/:user', function(req, res) {

    var userRoute = req.params.user;
    checkUserRoute(userRoute, res)

    });


function checkUserRoute(userRoute, res){

    var User = require('../models/user');


    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  userRoute }, function(err, user) {

        if (err){
            return done(err);
        }    

        if (user) {

            res.render('user.ejs', { title: userRoute, message: '' });
        } else {

            res.send(404);
        }

    });

}
```

My (beginners) understanding of MVC is that it would go in the models folder but then why in the tutorial I followed for Passport are the db connections in the the config folder?

This is the folder structure of the tutorial I used for the passport authentication part of my app:

http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local#application-structure

Even the default express app install is confusing. The default express app has a folder called routes but then it places app.get code in the app.js file which sits in the root folder not in the routes(controllers) folder.

Is this right or wrong to place the db connection there in my controllers/routes.js file? If it is wrong where should I place it and how should I call the function which accesses the mongo database?

Is the mongoose user schema code in the correct place?

Should the config/passport.js file contain mongoose db connections?

Answer (score 2):

**1. Should the config/passport.js file contain mongoose db connections?**
You can put your mongoose db connections in a separate file called `db.js`, then `import` or `require` that file in `passport.js`. So your config folder could look like this

> `/config
>       /db.js
>       /passport.js`

**2. Is the mongoose user schema code in the correct place?**
Yes, but you should capitalize the first letter of your model files to follow convention `User.js`.

**3. Is this right or wrong to place the db connection there in my controllers/routes.js file? If it is wrong where should I place it and how should I call the function which accesses the mongo database?**
You are not placing your db connection in the `routes.js` file. Your connection to your db should go in your config folder `config/db.js`. You would then export the file `module.exports = db;` and require it `var db = require('/config/db.js');` in your `controllers/routes.js` file. Now you will have access to your db connection. You could now run Mongo queries and methods in your controllers files, which is where your app's logic should go.

Your Model only speaks to your Controller, not the View. Similarly, your View only speaks to your Controller. Keeping your code organized this way will make your life much easier when your app gets more complicated.

Comment: Disagree with the capitalization point in second point.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose

Comment: @MuhammadRehanQadri The doc's state model names should be capitalized: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Answer (score 0):

I would add another 'services' folder and add some kind of db-accessor service in there.
You can still place all your db configs in your config file and let the service take it from there.

Another nice thing you can do is define the passport mongo-strategy in a separate module
so that it will also be replaceable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get up and running more quickly with node, express, and mongo, take a look at [**sails.js**](http://sailsjs.org). It's the most popular node.js MVC framework nowadays, and will help you spin up this type of project more easily.